# Using check to validate a string in Kotlin fails

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, exception, kotlin

I have an application where users have to enter different strings. Depending on the nature of the string in the application, it has to follow some rules, for example if it is a name it must begin with a letter.

I wrote a rule to be sure that a string is valid, in the case of a string that must start with a letter I wrote the following rule:

```
fun String.isFirstCharALetter(): Boolean = this[0].isLetter()
```

A function extension checks all the rules that apply to a specific string:

```
fun String.validateName(): String {
    check(this.isFirstCharALetter()) { "The first character of a name can only be a letter" }
    //... other checks
    return this
}
```

I use this function extension to instantiate a `Name` only if the string is valid (at least it is my intention):

```
data class Name(val value: String) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(strg: String) {
            Name(value= strg.validate())
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the following unit test:

```
@Test
fun test_assert_name() {
    assertFailsWith<IllegalStateException> { Name("8foo") }
}
```

Since *8foo* does not begin with a letter, I expect that an `IllegalStateException` exception is raised when a `Name` is instantiated with this string, so the test above must succeed.

But the test fails with the following message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected an exception of class java.lang.IllegalStateException to be thrown, but was completed successfully.
```

Does anyone see where I do an error ?

Comment: When you do `Name("8foo")` you're not invoking the method of the companion object. You're invoking the constructor (something like `new Name("8foo")` in Java)

Comment: you are right @Pelocho, the constructor has to be private, see my answer

Comment: Where did this pattern of putting an income function on a companion object come from? I’ve seen it twice in the past two days. Seems like it would make code fragile, like it did here.

Comment: *invoke function

Comment: I found several examples of using `invoke` in a companion object (for example: [kotlinlang](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/compiler-doesnt-consider-companion-invoke-as-construction-alternative/5113)). Why do you say that it make code fragile?

Answer (score 1):

To run invoke operator you needed to call

```
val name = Name("8foo")
name("8foo")
```

Then invoke will be called with exception

Maybe you should check first letter at init{} section?

```
class Name(private val string:String) {

    init{
        check(false){"Error"}
    }
```

You also can use regex to check if string starts with letter

Comment: Beware of regex! For a simple task like this, using a regex is totally overkill. Take a look at https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

As stated [here](https://proandroiddev.com/til-about-operator-overloading-in-kotlin-and-the-invoke-operator-da3686ef4694): *The invoke() operator allows instances of your classes to be called as functions.* (I could not find the description of `invoke` in the official documentation, if anyone knows where it is...)

Taking the definition above @Илья Кузьмин is right, I can use an `init` block.

But if I declare the constructor of my class `Name` as `private`,  I have the behaviour I want. `invoke` is then used when I instantiate a `Name` object:

```
data class Name private constructor(val value: String) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(value: String) = Name(value= value.validate())
    }
}
```

After making this fix all my tests succeeds.